Corrupted incorruptible saints (Catholicism)
Why does the Catholic Church promote the bodies of certain individuals as "incorruptibles" when their bodies have clearly corrupted?  Further, why does the Catholic Church hide the corruption and artificially delay corruption, such as a rubber mask in the case of Padre Pio to hide his decayed head, or storing bodies in environmentally controlled coffins, or injecting with formaldehyde?  How is the latter "incorruptible" evidence of anything supernatural, when the natural corruption is either hidden or delayed through very non-supernatural means?
For example this Wikipedia list, almost all the "incorruptibles" are described as corrupted and requiring wax  to cover up their face and hands.  Why does their true state need to be hidden?
If they are all corrupted, why does the Catholic Church maintain the appearance of incorruption?

As presented here, "their bodies have clearly corrupted", "hide the corruption", "the case of Padre Pio", etc. are all unsubstantiated statements. The question would be greatly improved by including explicit quotations from reputable sources about each claim.

Padre Pio is not considered to be totally incorrupt. Only part of his body shows incorruptibility.

I guess the other part of what I'm getting at here is if "incorruptible" means "not as corrupted as expected", then why the effort on the part of the Catholic church to artificially hide or delay natural corruption of the "incorruptibles"?  This seems highly suspicious.

Frame issue...
You are clearly not understanding the same thing as the catholic church about the term "incorruptible" it does not mean "never decays".

In the realm of Catholicism, an incorrupt saint is one whose body experiences little, no, or delayed decomposition after death. It is believed that divine intervention has allowed a number of human bodies to forgo the normal decomposition process as a symbol of the deceased’s holiness while alive on earth, and can also be perceived as the person’s mortal remains being prepared for the resurrection of the body at the end of time. - Tekton Ministries

Now another thing that people seem to forget is that "incorruptible" saints are generally very old. Like how old? most of them are hundreds of years old. A human body should be dust, all the soft tissue should be gone!

For those who are embalmed and buried in a coffin five to 10 years is a more typical decomposition timeline, he said [Wescott]. At that point, the tissue is gone and only bones remain. - LifeScience

Here is a list of some of the incorruptibles. Notice how the majority of them should only be bones if even that much remained. Died in 350 AD and St Silvan still has skin?! (Yes, there is protective seals on it now, but what about the past 1000+ years before they did that?!)

St. Silvan 350 – Dubrovnik, Croatia
St. Anthony of Padua (tongue) 1231 – Padua, Italy
St. Clare of Assisi 1253 – Assisi, Italy
St. Zita 1272 – Lucca, Italy
St. Catherine of Siena (head) 1380 – Siena, Italy
St. Rita 1457 – Cascia, Italy
St. Catherine of Bologna 1463 – Bologna, Italy
St. Francis Xavier 1552 – Goa, India
St. Vincent de Paul 1660 – Paris, France
St. Veronica Giuliani 1727 – Citta de Castello, Italy
St. Teresa Margaret 1770- Florence, Italy
St. John Vianney 1859 – Ars, France
St. Catherine Laboure 1876 – Paris, France
Blessed Pope Pius IX 1878 – St. Peter’s Basilica, Vatican City
St. Bernadette of Lourdes 1879 – Nevers, France
St. John Bosco 1888 – Turin, Italy
St. Frances Xavier Cabrini 1917 – Manhattan, New York
St. Pope John XXIII 1963 – St. Peter’s Basilica, Vatican City
St. Padre Pio 1968 – San Giovanni Rotondo, Italy


Catholic Incorruptibles: Slow decay, No decay, or delayed decay. Not just "No decay"

Why are they called "incorruptible" if none are actually incorruptible?  They should be called "less corruptible than we expected".  Also, why the efforts to hide and artificially delay corruption that is occurring?  That seems dishonest.

@yters Because basically they should all be a fine powder with a bare skeleton above the dust. As for the efforts to preserve bodies of saints that were naturally slow-to/didn't decay, is as honest as using medicine instead of expecting faith healthing to cure everything. There is nothing dishonest about saying "We found this saint's body X years after they died, they should be "gone" but they aren't, so we are doing our best to maintain what God set in motion"

The point of "incorruptibles" is precisely that they are being preserved through supernatural means.  To then use artificial means to both preserve and hide corruption, plus not transparently making that clear to viewers, is quite different than helping people live longer through medicine.  A better analogy is if Jesus said he was going to heal a leper miraculously, and then healed him using modern medicine.  In that case, people would consider Jesus a sham.  Plenty of non catholics have naturally preserved bodies, as well as many preserved artificially, such as Lenin.

@yters ultimately you prefer your own definition of "incorruptible", and if you use your definition then you are correct. They are decaying. However the point still stands, without being given the benefit of preservation treatment upon their deaths, many of the "incorruptible" saints are "as if" they were mummified or given modern embalming. You may disagree with how the catholic church definies incorruptible. Personally if someone is usually dust and bones in 20 years... a body with skin that is 50-500y old is significant. And this feature is not always a sign of a saint. Nor a requirement.

I guess my overall point is that there are a number of non Catholics who have extraordinarily preserved bodies, both through artificial and natural means, although none are truly incorruptible.  So, if these  "incorruptibles" also are not truly incorruptible, and are preserved artificially, then it isn't clear whether there is anything truly supernatural going on here.

@yters I am aware of many naturally preserved bodies, how many are naturally preserved in "bad" circumstances? Like no "bog man" or "oldest ice age mummified" or such. And not "modern embalming" and not "proper ancient mummification" etc. The incorruptibles fall into the category of "we didn't try to preserve them" corpses. Which is hard to find anything about while googling. How many "tossed into the tombs" or "tossed into a wooden box" non-saint preserved bodies do you know about from the 1500s or so? I am guessing that there must be based on your reasoning, but it is hard to find any...

There are lots of articles if you google "natural mummies".  Some are mummified by things like bogs or frozen, but others get unintentionally preserved in their graves by the surrounding environment, like extra salt in the ground.  The latter would appear to be miraculously preserved to an uninformed observer.  So, with the incorruptible saints, it'd be important to determine whether their extraordinary preservation could be explained by their environment.  And even if no obvious environmental effect was determined, there could always be an undiscovered preservative agent.

Corrupted incorruptible saints according to Catholicism?
Why does the Catholic Church promote the bodies of certain individuals as "incorruptibles" when their bodies have clearly corrupted?
Do you have any examples to support your statement?
If a body shows signs of corruption, the Church would not hold it to be incorruptible. That is basic evidence, the Church can not ignore.
As for your question about Padre Pio’s face, his face was covered with a lifelike silicone mask in order to help the skin from getting damaged from sunlight and from individuals cleaning the face for public viewing. This type of thing has happened to the face of St. Bernadette.
Not every saint is expected to have an incorruptible corpse. Although incorruptibility is recognized as supernatural, it is no longer counted as a miracle in the recognition of a saint (The Incorruptibles).
Embalmed bodies were not recognized as incorruptibles. For example, although the body of Pope John XXIII remained in a remarkably intact state after its exhumation, Church officials remarked that the body had been embalmed and additionally there was a lack of oxygen in his sealed triple coffin.
Incorruptibility is seen as distinct from the good preservation of a body, or from mummification. Incorruptible bodies are often said to have the odour of sanctity, exuding a sweet or floral, pleasant aroma.
Incorruptibilty is not reserved to the Catholic Church alone. There are a number of Orthodox Saints who have incorrupt bodies.
Nowadays the Catholic Church is striving to better understand why some Saints are preserved from corruption, thus seeing if the preservation is indeed miraculous or not. "These saints are in a class by themselves. Even though incorruptibility does not automatically confer sainthood upon the subject, it is still properly appreciated by the Church as a supernatural occurrences. The Church thus seeks the help of scientists and other professional to understand this question in a more modern light!

The lack of formal explanations on this subject seems to stem from the fact that this is an area of expertise for the scientific (professional) community and not the Church to investigate.
"Over the last 15 years, however, a new view of the Incorruptibles has begun to emerge. At the Vatican's request, Italian pathologists, chemists, and radiologists have been poring over the bodies of the ancient men and women interred in church reliquaries. Charged with gleaning new information about the lives of the saints and assisting in the conservation of sacred remains, they have also brought science to the altars of Europe's cathedrals. Already, they have examined more than two dozen saints and beati, shedding light on the mystery of their preservation. While some saints were clearly mummified by their devout followers, others were protected from decay by environmental conditions, raising new questions about incorruptibility. "What is a miracle?" asks Ezio Fulcheri, a pathologist at the University of Genoa and one of the leading researchers on the Incorruptibles. "It's something unexplainable, a special event that may occur in different ways." The causes may seem mysterious "but don't exclude [rare] natural processes that are different from the normal course of things." - The Incorruptibles.


If Padre Pio is incorruptible, why would the sun corrupt his face?  This article says he is in fact pretty corrupted http://thecatechist.com/the-controversy-over-padre-pios-incorrupt-body/

@yters That is the opinion of that site. Everyone knows sunlight can darken the skin on living persons. Why should the incorruptible individuals be different!

Or perhaps move the body out of the sunlight?  Methinks there are more plausible motives for the mask than sunscreen :)

Archbishop Domenico D'Ambrosio, who was at the exhumation of Pio, said "The top part of the skull is partly skeletal but the chin is perfect and the rest of the body is well preserved.".  Can a partly skeletal skull be considered incorruptible?

@MikeBorden So, you want a 100% incorruptibility of the body, from head to toe, to be considered incorruptible?

@jongricafort That is what the word means:  Not subject to decay.

@MikeBorden "Incorruptibility is a Catholic and Orthodox belief that divine intervention allows some human bodies (specifically saints and beati) to completely or partially avoid the normal process of decomposition after death as a sign of their holiness." This is the Church definition of incorruptibility. Your understanding is not accurate.

So, incorruptible means subject to partial decay to some degree or another according to the Catholic Church?
